# C++ invoke method from string

Tags: c++, qt

There is in Qt such functionality: `QMetaObject::invokeMethod(QObject * obj, const char * member, ...)`, which invokes method from string (member). How can I do the same (or similar)? Thanks)

Comment: You should ask yourself the question if you really need that.

Comment: Did you look at QtMetaObject source code?! That's the way (one of...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do this in pure c++, but you can read about reflection/introspect in c++ in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41453/how-can-i-add-reflection-to-a-c-application) question

Comment: @CAMOBAP: Of course you can call methods depending on a `string`. The simplest example being a `map<std::string, std::function<void()>>`. You can even do this for variably long argument lists, including a runtime check for call signature correctness (but it gets a bit ugly).

Comment: Actually I feel the need to give a downvote, because answering such a broad question with simply "you can't" is wrong and it simply isn't true.

Answer (score 4):

A similar thing can be achieved with a `map<std::string, std::function<void()>>`:

```
std::map<std::string, std::function<void()>> funs;
funs["hello world"] = [] () { std::cout << "hello world"; };
funs["hello world"]();
```

The question is *how similar do you want it?* *How "native" should the call look like?*. You can do things like:

```
void foobar(int, float);

...

    invoke("foobar", 5, 5.f);
```

but the implementation looks hacky and is non-trivial.

There is [a related problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11262039/76722):

> You can get pretty far with variadic templates and some template/virtual techniques. With the following codes, you'll be able to do something like:

```
std::string select_string (bool cond, std::string a, std::string b) {
    return cond ? a : b;
}

int main () {
    Registry reg;
    reg.set ("select_it", select_string);
    reg.invoke ("select_it", "1 John Wayne"));
    reg.invoke ("select_it", "0 John Wayne"));
}
```

i.e. where the argument list is dissected into a real argument list for a native function call. With variadic templates you can do a lot of things; I am not sure if you *should*.